# After adding add_role to functions.php and creating a user, can not login into admin

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles

I'm trying to add a specific role to manage my custom post types and I'm stuck at the very beginning.

I've added `add_role()` to the functions.php file as following:

```
add_role('resourcerer', 'Resourcerer', array('read_internal_jobs'));
```

and created a user with that role. However, when I try to login with a new user I would get an error `You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.` I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here :S

When registering my Custom Post Type I've got the following settings:

```
'capability_type' => array('internal_job', 'internal_jobs'),
'map_meta_cap' => true,
```

which, if I understand the [register_post_type() Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) correctly, by specifying `capability_type` the `capabilities` strings will be constructed respectively using the strings specified in the `capability_type`, for example: edit_internal_jobs, publish_internal_jobs and so on.

I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the "normal" capabilites that are needed to login are missing. You should simply load the capabilites of some default role and attach them to your custom role before using it on a user.

---

**EDIT:** Solution from @dashalune (OP):

```
add_role('resourcerer', 'Resourcerer'); 
$role =& get_role('resourcerer'); 
$role->add_cap('read');
```

Comment: thanks. I've added the 'read' capability, so at least I could login and see admin side. Here is my code if anyone will find it useful: add_role('resourcerer', 'Resourcerer');
$role =& get_role('resourcerer');
$role->add_cap('read');

Answer (score 2):

This is a full working example of custom roles for a custom made role (via add_role) for a specific theme:

```
function add_theme_caps() {
    $role = get_role( 'roletypename' );
    // create if neccesary
    if (!$role) $role = add_role('roletypename', 'Role Name'); 
    // add theme specific roles
    $role->add_cap('delete_posts');
    $role->add_cap('delete_published_posts');
    $role->add_cap('edit_posts');
    $role->add_cap('edit_published_posts');
    $role->add_cap('publish_posts');
    $role->add_cap('read');
    $role->add_cap('upload_files');
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps');
```